# Euclidean distance of points coordinates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with six columns, first three columns contain *x*, *y* and *z* reference coordinate, and the next three - coordinates of some point. I want to put euclidean distance between those two points in new column of the dataframe. I think about using `numpy.linalg.norm` via `pandas.apply` method, but I don't know what is the best method to parse dataframe row for numpy function. Could you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You might not need any fancy magic here:

```
df['dist'] = np.sqrt( (df.x1-df.x2)**2 + (df.y1-df.y2)**2 + (df.z1-df.z2)**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it:

```
p1 = df[['x1', 'y1', 'z1']]
p2 = df[['x2', 'y2', 'z2']]

df['dist'] = ((p1 - p2)**2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5
```