# Checking min distance between multiple slices of dataframe of co-ordinates

Tags: python, pandas, list, min

Having two sets of lists with cells ID

```
A = [4, 6, 2493, 2494, 2495]
B = [3, 7, 4983, 4982, 4984, 4981, 4985, 2492, 2496]
```

And each cell from the upper lists has `X, Y` coordinates in a seperate columns in a df, each.

df

```
cell_ID; X ;Y
1; 5; 6
2; 10; 6
...
```

Where values in the `A`, `B` list are the ones in `cell_id` column. How can I find the `sum` of distances between cells in A and B, but primarly looking at cells in `A` in relationship to `B`? So I have to calculate 5 (A lenght) distances for each cell in A, take `min()` of those 5 and `sum()` all those nine min values. I hope that makes sense

I was thinking the following:

1. Take first value from list A (this is cell with id = 4) and calculate distance between all cells in B and take further only the `min` value
2. Repeat step 1 with all other values in A
3. Make a `sum()` of all distances

I tried with the code below... but failed

```
def sum_distances(df, i, col_X='X', col_Y='Y'):
    for i in range(A)    
    return  (((df.iloc[B][col_X] - df.iloc[i,2])**2 + (df.iloc[B][col_Y] - df.iloc[i,3])**2)**0.5).min
```

I don't know how to integrate `min()` and `sum()` at the same time.

Comment: Hi there, you provided `df` with columns `cellID, X, Y`. Are there 2 such dataframes - eg `df1` and `df2`, each with columns `cellID, X, Y`?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that lists A and B hold the indexes of the dataframes `df1` and `df2` respectively. Is this correct? If so, and if you want the distances between cells in A and B, shouldn't list A and list B be the same length?

Comment: Hi! There's only one df where all distances for all cell id's are located. Regarding the second comment - you're correct. I'll re-edit the question. I'm looking for the shortest distances from cells in B only, but looking at the distances to cells in A

Comment: Is this the distance equation you must use: `sqrt((X_A-X_B)**2 + (Y_A-Y_B)**2)`

Comment: Yes! `math.sqrt` didn't work at first, so i used `**0.5`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Last comment: unless I'm mistaken, you just want to get the distances and then find the shortest distance. Correct me if this is missing something.

Comment: Correct. E.g. i want to get the min distance from cell 3 to [4, 6, 2493, 2494, 2495], from cell 7 to [4, 6, 2493, 2494, 2495], ... and in the end - sum() all those minimum distances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're looking for the [Euclidean distance between `(x,y)` co-ordinates](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/DistanceFormula.shtml). Here is one possible approach (based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846092/4057186))

Generate some dummy data in the same format of the OP

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 9, 8, 7, 6]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15,2), columns=['X','Y'], index=range(15))
df.index.name = 'CellID'
print('Raw data\n{}'.format(df))

Raw data
               X         Y
CellID                    
0       0.125591  0.890772
1       0.754238  0.644081
2       0.952322  0.099627
3       0.090804  0.809511
4       0.514346  0.041740
5       0.678598  0.230225
6       0.594182  0.432634
7       0.005777  0.891440
8       0.925187  0.045035
9       0.903591  0.238609
10      0.187591  0.255377
11      0.252635  0.149840
12      0.513432  0.972749
13      0.433606  0.550940
14      0.104991  0.440052
```

To get the minimum distance between each index of B and A

```
# Get df at indexes from list A: df_A
df_A = df.iloc[A,]
# For df at each index from list B (df.iloc[b,]), get distance to df_A: d
dist = []
for b in B:
    d = (pd.DataFrame(df_A.values - df.iloc[b,].values)**2).sum(1)**0.5
    dist.append(d.min())

print('Sum of minimum distances is {}'.format(sum(dist)))
```

Output (for sum of minimum distances between each index of B and A)

```
Sum of minimum distances is 2.36509386378
```

Comment: Many thanks! Works great! If I may, i've been trying madly for the past 2 hours, what would it needed to be restructured if I am trying to repeat this approach multiple times? Not between A and B as you wrote the solution, but between other list as well, E.g. original list A is the list of neighbour cells of cell 5, similar B are id's of neighbour cells of some other cell. The neat solution you proposed works great for having 1 case. How could we calculate for more of those lists?